# Testing a file under lib folder with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a file located at `lib/pdf_helper.rb` that I want to test. What is the first step I need to do? I did a test for controllers. Another thing, I'm new on Rspec. That's why I'm asking.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439828/where-do-rspec-tests-for-code-under-lib-go?rq=1